# Apply multiple preprocessing steps to a column in sklearn Pipeline + ColumnTransformer

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I was trying sklearn pipeline for the first time and using Titanic dataset. I want to first impute missing value in `Embarked` and then do one hot encoding. While in `Sex` attribute, I just want to do one hot encoding. So, I have the below steps in which two steps are for `Embarked`. But it is not working as expected as the `Embarked` column remains in addition to its one hot encoding as shown in the output(column having 'S').

If I do imputation and one hot encoding for `Embarked` in single step, it is working as expected.

What is the reason behind this or I am doing something wrong? Also, I didn't find any information related to this.

```
categorical_cols_impute = ['Embarked']
categorical_impute = Pipeline([
    ("mode_impute", SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='constant', fill_value='S')),
#     ("one_hot", OneHotEncoder(sparse=False))
])
categorical_cols = ['Embarked', 'Sex']
categorical_one_hot = Pipeline([
    ("one_hot", OneHotEncoder(sparse=False))
])
preprocesor = ColumnTransformer([
    ("cat_impute", categorical_impute, categorical_cols_impute),
    ("cat_one_hot", categorical_one_hot, categorical_cols)
], remainder="passthrough")
pipe = Pipeline([
    ("preprocessor", preprocesor),
#     ("model", RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0))
])
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ColumnTransformer` transformers are applied in parallel, not sequentially.  So in your example, `Embarked` ends up in your transformed data twice: once from the first transformer, keeping its string type, and again from the second transformer, this time one-hot encoded (but not imputed first!(?)).

So just uncomment the second step in the embarked pipeline, and remove `Embarked` from `categorical_cols`.

See also [Consistent ColumnTransformer for intersecting lists of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62225230/10495893) (but I don't think it's quite a duplicate).