# Sklearn ColumnTransformer + Pipeline = TypeError

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, preprocessor, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to use properly pipelines and column transformers from sklearn but always end up with an error. I reproduced it in the following example.

```
# Data to reproduce the error
X = pd.DataFrame([[1,  2 , 3,  1 ],
                  [1, '?', 2,  0 ],
                  [4,  5 , 6, '?']],
                 columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

#SimpleImputer to change the values '?' with the mode
impute = SimpleImputer(missing_values='?', strategy='most_frequent')

#Simple one hot encoder
ohe = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse=False)

col_transfo = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ('missing_vals', impute, ['B', 'D']),
    ('one_hot', ohe, ['A', 'B'])],
    remainder='passthrough'
)
```

Then calling the transformer as follows:

```
col_transfo.fit_transform(X)
```

Returns the following error:

```
TypeError: Encoders require their input to be uniformly strings or numbers. Got ['int', 'str']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ColumnTransformer` applies its transformers in parallel, not in sequence.  So the `OneHotEncoder` sees the un-imputed column `B` and balks at the mixed types.

In your case, it's probably fine to just impute on all the columns, and then encode `A, B`:

```py
encoder = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ('one_hot', ohe, ['A', 'B'])],
    remainder='passthrough'
)
preproc = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('impute', impute),
    ('encode', encoder),
    # optionally, just throw the model here...
])
```

If it's important that future missing values in `A,C` cause errors, then similarly wrap `impute` into its own `ColumnTransformer`.

See also [Apply multiple preprocessing steps to a column in sklearn pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65554163/10495893)

Comment: Thanks. I got it since then. The sklearn documentation is just missing the fact that it's not applied sequentially but in parallel. That would have avoid a lot of headaches :)

Answer (score 0):

It's giving you an error because `OneHotEncoder` accepts just one format of data. In your case, it's a mixture of `numbers` and `object`. To overcome this issue you can separate the pipeline after `imputer` and `OneHotEncoder` to use `astype` method on the output of the `imputing` . Something like:

```
ohe.fit_transform(imputer.fit_transform(X[['A','B']]).astype(float))
```

Comment: But after applying the SimpleImputer, we should only have integers in every columns, shouldn't we? Also, if I ended up doing that, I will have to deal with train and test separately, while a single pipeline allows a single fit.

Comment: No, You are confusing `pipeline` with `ColumnTransformer` . In pipeline output of each transformer is the input of next one. But, `ColumnTransformer` in your code is doing different transformations on the different columns of `X` dataframe.

Comment: The idea is to be able to use ``col_transfo`` into a pipeline afterwards. For instance ``Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessing', col_transfo), ('model', RandomForestClassifier)])``. WIth your solution, I feel like I will have to fit separately train, validation and test and manually transform the data frame to add up the new columns, remove column 'A' and 'B' and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not coming from the ColumnTransformer but from the OneHotEncoder object

```
col_transfo = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ('missing_vals', impute, ['B', 'D'])],
    remainder='passthrough'
)

col_transfo.fit_transform(X)
```

> array([[2, 1, 1, 3],
> [2, 0, 1, 2],
> [5, 0, 4, 6]], dtype=object)

```
ohe.fit_transform(X)
```

> TypeError: argument must be a string or number

OneHotEncoder is throwing this error because the object get mixed type of values (int + string) to encode on the same column, you need to cast the float columns to string in order to apply it