# ValueError: Shape mismatch: if categories is an array, The error is not resolved even after specifying the columns as indexes

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, one-hot-encoding

```py
    trf1=ColumnTransformer([("Infuse_val",SimpleImputer(strategy="mean"),[0])],remainder="passthrough")
    trf4=ColumnTransformer([("One_hot",OneHotEncoder(sparse=False,handle_unknown="ignore"),[1,4])],remainder="passthrough")
    trf2=ColumnTransformer([("Ord_encode",OrdinalEncoder(categories=["Strong","Mild"]),[3])],remainder="passthrough")
    trf3=ColumnTransformer([("scale",StandardScaler(),[0,2])],remainder="passthrough")
    pipe = Pipeline([
        ('trf1',trf1),
        ('trf2',trf2),
        ('trf3',trf3),
        ('trf4',trf4),
    ])
    pipe.fit(x_train,y_tarin)
```

Error

```
ValueError: Shape mismatch: if categories is an array, it has to be of shape (n_features,).
```

The table is

[image]

I don't understand what's the error here in my code?

Comment: Always provide the full error traceback; it provides valuable information about where the error gets raised from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error isn't about the column transformers, it's about the `OrdinalEncoder`. `categories` needs to be a list of lists: for each column, the list of categories in that column. Since you have just one column, `categories=[["Strong","Mild"]]` should work.

With just two categories, most subsequent algorithms won't care which one is 0 or 1, so here you could just use the default `auto`.

Finally, you'll have problems with your column transformers. The change the order (and names) of the columns, so by the end of the pipeline,  scaling columns 0 and 2 might not be the two numeric columns. The column order is predictable (transformers in order followed by passthrough), so you could manually keep track. But I would suggest a single column transformer with multiple pipelines instead.

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Male' . Even after doing above categories='auto' it throws the error

Comment: @AkashMukherjee That's possibly because of the third paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Hey Ben sorry to disturb you , but could you please elaborate your third para, what you said? I'm not able to understand. I did this :- trf=ColumnTransformer([("Infuse_val",SimpleImputer(strategy="mean"),[0]),
                        ("One_hot",OneHotEncoder(sparse=False,handle_unknown="ignore"),[1,4]),
                        ("scale",StandardScaler(),[0,1,2,3,4])])                                                                  What changes needs to be done here?

Comment: Ah, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/65554163/10495893.  The scaler sees the original columns 0--4, _not_ the already-imputed/encoded columns 0, 1, 4.