# I am trying to fill numerical and categorical values and convert categorical values with OneHotEncoder using ColumnTrandformer but its not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

i tried to fill dataframe with imputer and then perform onehotncoding on categorical values but when i apply any alogos to the transformed values it throws error , mentioned below code, and if i perform same task individually without using columntransformer it is working fine what am i doing wrong?

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

# Define the columns for different imputation strategies
mean_col = ['MinTemp', 'MaxTemp', 'Rainfall', 'WindGustSpeed', 'WindSpeed9am', 'WindSpeed3pm', 'Humidity9am', 'Humidity3pm', 'Pressure9am', 'Pressure3pm', 'Temp9am', 'Temp3pm']
median_col = ['Cloud9am', 'Cloud3pm']
mf_col = ['WindGustDir', 'WindDir9am', 'WindDir3pm', 'RainToday']
ohm_cols = ['Location','WindGustDir','WindDir9am','WindDir3pm','RainToday']

# Create a ColumnTransformer
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('trnf1', SimpleImputer(strategy='mean'), mean_col),
        ('trnf2', SimpleImputer(strategy='median'), median_col),
        ('trnf3', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent'), mf_col),
        ('trnf4', OneHotEncoder(drop='first', sparse=False), ohm_cols)
    ],
    remainder='drop'  # Drop columns not specified in transformers
)

# Fit and transform the training data
x_train_transformed = preprocessor.fit_transform(x_train)

# Transform the testing data
x_test_transformed = preprocessor.transform(x_test)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'SSW'
```

Below code is performing same task in pieces and its working fine:

```
im = SimpleImputer(strategy= 'mean')
x_train[mean_col] = im.fit_transform(x_train[mean_col])
x_test[mean_col] = im.transform(x_test[mean_col])

im_median = SimpleImputer(strategy='median')
x_train[median_col] = im_median.fit_transform(x_train[median_col])
x_test[median_col] = im_median.transform(x_test[median_col])

im_mf = SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')
x_train[mf_col] = im_mf.fit_transform(x_train[mf_col])
x_test[mf_col] = im_mf.transform(x_test[mf_col])
ohm  =OneHotEncoder(drop = 'first', sparse = False)
x_train_transformed = ohm.fit_transform(x_train1[ohm_cols])
x_test_transformed = ohm.transform(x_test1[ohm_cols])
```

Comment: Where exactly, and how are `x_train` and `x_test` defined? Please update your post to include the full error trace - see how to create a [mre].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply multiple preprocessing steps to a column in sklearn pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65554163/apply-multiple-preprocessing-steps-to-a-column-in-sklearn-pipeline)