# How to combine a pipeline for all types of features, for categorical features and numerical features in one ColumnTransformerr?

Tags: scikit-learn, pipeline, sklearn-pandas

Im trying to create a pipeline that combines :

1. Pipeline for all kinds of features, no matter the type (cleaning incorrect data by feature)
2. Pipeline for categorical features (categorical imputer)
3. Pipeline for numerical features (numerical imputer)

in a [sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html)¶.

This here is a piece of code for what I'm trying to do

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

alltypes = Pipeline([
    ('column_name_normalizer',ColumnNameNormalizer()),
    ('column_incorrect_data_cleaner',ColumnIncorrectDataCleaner(some_parameter),
])

num_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('imputer',CustomNumImputer(some_parameter)), # remplir les valeurs manquants
])

cat_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ("cat", CustomCatImputer(some_parameter))
])

full_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([
        ("alltypes",alltypes,allcolumns),
        ("num", num_pipeline, numfeat),
        ("cat",cat_pipeline,catfeat)
])

try:
    X = pd.DataFrame(full_pipeline.fit_transform(X).toarray())
except AttributeError:
    X = pd.DataFrame(full_pipeline.fit_transform(X))
```

However in the end I get a dataframe with more number of features than at the beginning which is due to the fact that all the features from the pipelines are concatenated, instead of an operator UNION being performed on them:

For instance I want to do some transformations on all features, then do some transformations on categorical features, and do some transformations on numerical features, but I want the outputing dataframe to be always the same size.

Do you know how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine the sequential power of `Pipeline`, e.g.

```py
cat_num_split = ColumnTransformer([
    ("num", num_pipeline, numfeat),
    ("cat", cat_pipeline, catfeat),
])
full_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ("alltypes", alltypes),
    ("cat_num", cat_num_split),
)]
```

There is a catch here: the `alltypes` transformer will result in a numpy array without information about which columns are which; your `cat_num_split` feature lists `numfeat` and `catfeat` will rely on your knowledge of which columns are which, and cannot use the column names.

An alternative, that doesn't run into the feature name issue, is to switch the order here.

```py
num_full_pipe = Pipeline([
    ("common", alltypes),
    ("num", num_pipeline),
])
cat_full_pipe = Pipeline([
    ("common", alltypes),
    ("cat", cat_pipeline),
])
full_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([
    ("num", num_full_pipe, numfeat),
    ("cat", cat_full_pipe, catfeat),
])
```

See also [Consistent ColumnTransformer for intersecting lists of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62225230/10495893).

Comment: I tried your second approach since you said this one will avoid the feature name issue. The ColumnTransformer in the end does seem to map my feature names to integers, but I guess you meant that this mapping can be easily retrieved by keeping in mind the order of features passed in the ColumnTransformer's pipelines. Is that what you meant ?

Comment: Right: if `alltypes` doesn't change the order or number of columns, then using indices will work fine.  But otherwise, you need to know which indices actually correspond to things you want to go into the numeric or categorical pipes.

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful!