# Why is SimpleImputer in ColumnTransformer creating additional Columns?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am following the machine learning book from Aurelion Geron.

I am experimenting with the `ColumnTransformer` class. When I include `SimplerImputer`, an additional columns was created. I understand that `SimplerImputer` is for filling up missing value in column `total_bedrooms` (column index 4 in result) , hence I am not clear why it is adding new column (column index: 10) in result.

When i do not include
the `SimplerImputer` from `ColumnTransformer`, but create an instance, and `fit_transform` the output of the `ColumnTransformer`, i will not get the additional column. Please advise.

```
category_att = X.select_dtypes(include='object').columns
num_att = X.select_dtypes(include='number').columns

transformer = ColumnTransformer(
    [
    ('adder', AttributeAdder(), num_att ),
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median'), ['total_bedrooms']),
    ('ohe', OneHotEncoder(), category_att)
    ],
    remainder = 'passthrough'
)
```

**Custom Class for adding two new feature/columns**

```
class AttributeAdder(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    
    def __init__(self, add_bed_room = False):
        self.add_bed_room = add_bed_room
    
    def fit(self,y=None):
        return self
    
    def transform(self,X,y=None):
        
        room_per_household = X.iloc[: , t_room ] / X.iloc[: , t_household ]
        population_per_household = X.iloc[: , t_population ] / X.iloc[: , t_household ]
        return np.c_[X,room_per_household,population_per_household]
```

Results
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Why

It's not the `SimpleImputer` exactly; it's the `ColumnTransformer` itself.  `ColumnTransformer` applies its transformers in parallel, not sequentially (see also [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62225230/10495893), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65554163/10495893)), so if a column gets passed to multiple transformers, you'll end up with that column multiple times in the output.  In your case, output column 4 comes from the `"adder"` on `total_bedrooms` (which has done nothing, so has missing values still), and output column 10 comes from the `"imputer"` (and so will have no missing values).

## Fixes

In this particular case, two approaches seem the easiest.

### Impute everything

Any of your numeric features that don't have missings won't be affected.  However, if you want the pipeline to error out on *future* data that has missing values, then don't do this.

```py
num_pipe = Pipeline([
    ("add_feat", AttributeAdder()),
    ("impute", SimpleImputer(strategy="median")),
])
transformer = ColumnTransformer(
    [
        ('num', num_pipe, num_att),
        ('cat', OneHotEncoder(), category_att),
    ],
    remainder = 'passthrough',
)
```

### Smaller transformer column sets

Since you don't actually need your `total_bedrooms` column for your `AttributeAdder`, you don't need to pass it into that transformer.  The specifics of this will depend on how you're using `t_rooms`, `t_households`, etc., but generally:

```py
transformer = ColumnTransformer(
    [
        ('adder', AttributeAdder(), [["total_rooms", "households", "population"]]),
        ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median'), ['total_bedrooms']),
        ('ohe', OneHotEncoder(), category_att)
    ],
    remainder = 'passthrough'  # now you're relying on this one much more
)
```

In a related approach, you have more flexibility in how the added features are computed.  Change your `AttributeAdder` to return *just* the new features (don't concatenate to `X` in the last step of `transform`), and rely on the `ColumnTransformer` to pass those features along.  (Note that we can't rely on `remainder` for those, but we can use `"passthrough"` as one of the transformers.)

```py
class AttributeAdder(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    ...
    def transform(self,X,y=None):
        ...
        return np.c_[room_per_household,population_per_household]


transformer = ColumnTransformer(
    [
        ('adder', AttributeAdder(), num_att),
        ('num', "passthrough", num_att.drop(['total_bedrooms'])),
        ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median'), ['total_bedrooms']),
        ('ohe', OneHotEncoder(), category_att)
    ],
    passthrough=True,  # if you have columns in neither of num_att and category_att that you want kept
)
```