# ColumnTransformer with non-trivially intersecting column domains

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I'm working with a housing dataset containing both numerical and categorical data. The only missing values in my data occur in two of the numerical features. As an example, consider `X` and `y` given by

```py
       bed  bath  acre_lot         state  zip_code  house_size
32104  7.0  10.0      2.75   Connecticut      6880      9360.0
85281  3.0   2.0      0.14    New Jersey      8753         NaN
48989  3.0   2.0      0.12    New Jersey      8830      1292.0
36620  2.0   1.0       NaN      New York     10029       842.0
80332  3.0   1.0      0.02  Pennsylvania     19143      1080.0
```

and

```
32104    7995000.0
85281     385000.0
48989     389000.0
36620     849000.0
80332     169999.0
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

respectively.

In order to combine datatype-specific preprocessing steps to these data, I'm using sklearn's `ColumnTransformer()` in my pipeline like so:

```py
num_features = ['bed', 'bath', 'acre_lot', 'house_size', 'zip_code']

num_transformer = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ('add_one', FunctionTransformer(lambda x: x+1)),
        ('box_cox_transformer', PowerTransformer(method='box-cox')),
    ]
)

knn_imputer = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ('knn_imputer', KNNImputer(n_neighbors=3))
    ]
)

cat_transformer = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ('one_hot_encoder', OneHotEncoder())
    ]
)

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ("numeric", num_transformer, num_features),
        ("imputer", knn_imputer, num_features),
        ("categorical", cat_transformer, ['state'])
    ]
)

pipe = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ('preprocessor', preprocessor)
    ]
)
```

However, `pd.DataFrame(pipe.fit_transform(X, y))` returns:

```py
         0         1         2         3         4    5     6         7   \
0  1.629439  1.642671  1.673082  1.589994 -1.487717  7.0  10.0  2.750000   
1 -0.033065  0.227110 -0.300638       NaN -0.227486  3.0   2.0  0.140000   
2 -0.033065  0.227110 -0.395869 -0.027153 -0.190590  3.0   2.0  0.120000   
3 -1.530245 -1.048445       NaN -1.134937  0.288592  2.0   1.0  1.003333   
4 -0.033065 -1.048445 -0.976576 -0.427903  1.617201  3.0   1.0  0.020000   

            8        9    10   11   12   13  
0  9360.000000   6880.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
1  3831.333333   8753.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  
2  1292.000000   8830.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  
3   842.000000  10029.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  
4  1080.000000  19143.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

From this output, it doesn't seem like the pipeline is composing the steps, meaning that the output of `num_transformer` is not the input of `knn_imputer`, which is what I wanted.

When I combine `num_transformer` and `knn_imputer` into a single step in `ColumnTransformer()`, the pipeline does what I want. But what if I wanted to perform the imputation step *after* the numerical transformations and one-hot encoding (i.e. using the transformed/encoded data for imputation)? It wouldn't be so easy to combine the `ColumnTransformer()` steps.

Is there a way to define a `ColumnTransformer` whose steps have non-trivially intersecting column domains and compose in sequence?

Comment: Show us a unit test that has the imputer as its final step, along with example output values.

Comment: I just updated the question to include a unit test, and realized that my question is entirely different now.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/67250392/10495893, https://stackoverflow.com/q/62225230/10495893

Answer (score 0):

When you process the same columns in a ColumnTransformer multiple times, the ColumnTransformer extracts the columns multiple times, gives each transformer a copy of the columns, and concatenates all of the columns together at the end. It does *not* give the output of one transformer to the input of another. That's what Pipeline is for.

So you have a set of columns which have had the steps of adding one and applying Box Cox, and a set of columns which have had the NaN's removed, but you have no columns where both transforms have been applied.

Instead, I would suggest using a Pipeline. You mention that you have a non-trivial intersection of columns. I presume this means that you also need a ColumnTransformer to select the columns you want to impute across. If you're okay imputing across every column, you could remove this.

Example:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer, PowerTransformer, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer
num_features = ['bed', 'bath', 'acre_lot', 'house_size', 'zip_code']

knn_imputer = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ('knn_imputer', KNNImputer(n_neighbors=3))
    ]
)

num_transformer = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ('add_one', FunctionTransformer(lambda x: x+1, feature_names_out='one-to-one')),
        ('box_cox_transformer', PowerTransformer(method='box-cox')),
    ]
)

cat_transformer = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ('one_hot_encoder', OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False))
    ]
)

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ("numeric", num_transformer, num_features),
        ("categorical", cat_transformer, ['state'])
    ],
    # Don't change feature name based on transformer
    verbose_feature_names_out=False,
)

preprocessor2 = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        # Add a feature from the OneHotEncoder to demonstrate that
        # you can select features from it.
        ("imputer", knn_imputer, num_features + ['state_Connecticut']),
    ],
    # If a column is not mentioned, keep it.
    remainder='passthrough',
    verbose_feature_names_out=False,
)

pipe = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
        ('preprocessor2', preprocessor2),
    ]
)

# This is needed to select columns by feature name in multiple steps of pipeline
pipe.set_output(transform="pandas")
print(pipe.fit_transform(X))
```

Output:

```
        bed      bath  acre_lot  house_size  zip_code  state_Connecticut  \
0  1.629439  1.642671  1.673082    1.487854 -1.487717                1.0   
1 -0.033065  0.227110 -0.300638   -1.659339 -0.227486                0.0   
2 -0.033065  0.227110 -0.395869    0.159324 -0.190590                0.0   
3 -1.530245 -1.048445 -0.557694   -0.054856  0.288592                0.0   
4 -0.033065 -1.048445 -0.976576    0.067018  1.617201                0.0   

   state_New_Jersey  state_New_York  state_Pennsylvania  
0               0.0             0.0                 0.0  
1               1.0             0.0                 0.0  
2               1.0             0.0                 0.0  
3               0.0             1.0                 0.0  
4               0.0             0.0                 1.0
```