# Why am I getting a data type error from my preprocessor?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection, data-preprocessing

I am having trouble creating a preprocessor for my data. My preprocessor consists of a pipeline for numerical features that imputes NaN and scales values. It also has a pipeline for categorical data that imputes NaN and target encodes. The final transformer is a selector that retains features that meet a certain criteria. When I fit my preprocessor to the data I get this error:

```
X_40 = preprocessor_40.fit_transform(X, y)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_33/4000599259.py in ?()
----> 1 X_40 = preprocessor_40.fit_transform(X, y)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_set_output.py in ?(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
    138     @wraps(f)
    139     def wrapped(self, X, *args, **kwargs):
--> 140         data_to_wrap = f(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
    141         if isinstance(data_to_wrap, tuple):
    142             # only wrap the first output for cross decomposition
    143             return (

/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in ?(self, X, y)
    723         self._validate_transformers()
    724         self._validate_column_callables(X)
    725         self._validate_remainder(X)
    726 
--> 727         result = self._fit_transform(X, y, _fit_transform_one)
    728 
    729         if not result:
    730             self._update_fitted_transformers([])

/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in ?(self, X, y, func, fitted, column_as_strings)
    669         except ValueError as e:
    670             if "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead" in str(e):
    671                 raise ValueError(_ERR_MSG_1DCOLUMN) from e
    672             else:
--> 673                 raise

/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/parallel.py in ?(self, iterable)
     59         iterable_with_config = (
     60             (_with_config(delayed_func, config), args, kwargs)
     61             for delayed_func, args, kwargs in iterable
     62         )
---> 63         return super().__call__(iterable_with_config)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in ?(self, iterable)
   1859             # If n_jobs==1, run the computation sequentially and return
   1860             # immediatly to avoid overheads.
   1861             output = self._get_sequential_output(iterable)
   1862             next(output)
-> 1863             return output if self.return_generator else list(output)
   1864 
   1865         # Let's create an ID that uniquely identifies the current call. If the
   1866         # call is interrupted early and that the same instance is immediately

/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in ?(self, iterable)
   1802         finally:
   1803             self.print_progress()
   1804             self._running = False
   1805             self._iterating = False
-> 1806             self._original_iterator = None

/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/parallel.py in ?(self, *args, **kwargs)
    119                 UserWarning,
    120             )
    121             config = {}
    122         with config_context(**config):
--> 123             return self.function(*args, **kwargs)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in ?(transformer, X, y, weight, message_clsname, message, **fit_params)
    889     be multiplied by ``weight``.
    890     """
    891     with _print_elapsed_time(message_clsname, message):
    892         if hasattr(transformer, "fit_transform"):
--> 893             res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    894         else:
    895             res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
    896 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_set_output.py in ?(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
    138     @wraps(f)
    139     def wrapped(self, X, *args, **kwargs):
--> 140         data_to_wrap = f(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
    141         if isinstance(data_to_wrap, tuple):
    142             # only wrap the first output for cross decomposition
    143             return (

/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in ?(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    877             # fit method of arity 1 (unsupervised transformation)
    878             return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
    879         else:
    880             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)
--> 881             return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/_univariate_selection.py in ?(self, X, y)
    463             Returns the instance itself.
    464         """
    465         self._validate_params()
    466 
--> 467         X, y = self._validate_data(
    468             X, y, accept_sparse=["csr", "csc"], multi_output=True
    469         )
    470 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in ?(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    580                 if "estimator" not in check_y_params:
    581                     check_y_params = {**default_check_params, **check_y_params}
    582                 y = check_array(y, input_name="y", **check_y_params)
    583             else:
--> 584                 X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
    585             out = X, y
    586 
    587         if not no_val_X and check_params.get("ensure_2d", True):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in ?(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, estimator)
   1102         raise ValueError(
   1103             f"{estimator_name} requires y to be passed, but the target y is None"
   1104         )
   1105 
-> 1106     X = check_array(
   1107         X,
   1108         accept_sparse=accept_sparse,
   1109         accept_large_sparse=accept_large_sparse,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in ?(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator, input_name)
    876                         )
    877                     array = xp.astype(array, dtype, copy=False)
    878                 else:
    879                     array = _asarray_with_order(array, order=order, dtype=dtype, xp=xp)
--> 880             except ComplexWarning as complex_warning:
    881                 raise ValueError(
    882                     "Complex data not supported\n{}\n".format(array)
    883                 ) from complex_warning

/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_array_api.py in ?(array, dtype, order, copy, xp)
    181     if xp is None:
    182         xp, _ = get_namespace(array)
    183     if xp.__name__ in {"numpy", "numpy.array_api"}:
    184         # Use NumPy API to support order
--> 185         array = numpy.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    186         return xp.asarray(array, copy=copy)
    187     else:
    188         return xp.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in ?(self, dtype)
   1996     def __array__(self, dtype: npt.DTypeLike | None = None) -> np.ndarray:
   1997         values = self._values
-> 1998         arr = np.asarray(values, dtype=dtype)
   1999         if (
   2000             astype_is_view(values.dtype, arr.dtype)
   2001             and using_copy_on_write()

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'RL'
```

I suspect it is an issue with my column transformer rather than the selector as I have been having problems with it and this is a new approach to selecting features I am trying out. However, I am not sure. The follow code is how I defined my preprocessors:

```
def get_preprocessor(percent, categorical, numerical):

    #Pipeline to impute missing values and scale numerical variables
    numerical_processes = Pipeline(steps = [('imputer_num', SimpleImputer(strategy = 'constant', fill_value = 0)),
                                           ('scaler', StandardScaler())])
    
    #Pipeline to impute missing values and encode categorical variables
    categorical_processes = Pipeline(steps = [('imputer_cat', SimpleImputer(strategy = 'constant', fill_value = 'None')),
                                          ('encoder', ce.TargetEncoder())])
    
    #Selector to retain only features that meet a certain threshold in an f_regression
    selector = SelectPercentile(f_regression, percentile = percent)
    
    #create a preprocessor that wraps up processes for both numerical and categorical variables
    Preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
            transformers = [('numeric', numerical_processes, numerical), 
                            ('categorical', categorical_processes, categorical),
                           ('selector', selector, numerical + categorical)])
    return Preprocessor
```

```
preprocessor_full = get_preprocessor(0, categorical, numerical)
preprocessor_40 = get_preprocessor(40, categorical, numerical)
preprocessor_70 = get_preprocessor(70, categorical, numerical)
```

I have checked how I define categorical and numerical columns many times and I am finding no issues. When it refers to RL in the error that is one of the values in a column called MSZoning and it is listed in categorical, but not numerical. So I don't know why I am getting this error if it's in the right place. It is also the first categorical feature in my column indices for reference.

I tried specifying two different selectors to work in my pipelines rather than having it as a step in the column transformer and I got the same error. However, when I had the selector in both the numerical and categorical pipelines I fit and transformed the dataframe with those rather than combining it all into a column transformer and it worked. I don't know why the column transformer is giving me issues. I know you might say that I should just do without it, but I just want to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ColumnTransformer` applies its transformers in parallel, horizontally stacking the outputs (not in sequence, replacing columns in place). See e.g. [Consistent ColumnTransformer for intersecting lists of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62225230/10495893)

So your feature selection transformer is getting the original categorical columns, not the target-encoded ones, and balks at the string values.

Instead, you should use a `Pipeline` whose first step is a column transformer, and whose second step is a feature selection.